# How to set columns while reading a data-frame from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I try to read data from a CSV file using the following command:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(finp, header=None, columns = cols)
```

As a result I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'
```

I resolve the problem in the following way:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(finp, header=None)
df.columns = cols
```

But I still wonder why it did not worked the first way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no parameter 'columns'. Use 'names' instead of it.

By the way, do you have a header rows in your CSV?

Comment: Thank you. I do not have a header in the CSV.